# Delete old files based on date extracted from filename by custom rules

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to find best way to automatically delete my old SQL backup files on s3 based on following rules:

1. keep all backups for last 7 day
2. keep last backup of each day for last 6 month
3. keep last backup of each week for last 2 year
4. keep last backup of each month for more than 2 years old file.

My file names contains backup datetime as following **XX_backup_2016_12_09_150003_4066809.bak**.

What do you recommend? AWS Lambda or what?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [S3 Lifecycle Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html) with [ObjectTagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html).

You can use [S3 Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) to [trigger a lambda for each PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html). Your lambda can create tags on the S3 objects based on the rules you have outlined. The file name will be input to the lambda from the S3 Event.

That is:

1. keep all backups for last 7 day (default tag for 7 day retention)
2. keep last backup of each day for last 6 month (tag as 6 month retention)
3. keep last backup of each week for last 2 year (tag as 2 year retention)
4. keep last backup of each month for more than 2 years old file (tag for x retention)

The lambda can deal with edge cases to determine if a particular file is both required for 6 months and 2 years. A default tag could be used if no other tag can be applied for the 7 day retention.

Then the lifecycle rules with expiration can be created and applied according to the tag.